# Will my sqlite database occupy less space if I insert nulls instead of zeros

Tags: sqlite

I have a table where most of the values inserted in one of the columns are 0. Should the database be smaller if I insert nulls instead of zeros?

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see for yourself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the SQLite [record format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format), both `NULL` and the integer `0` need only a type code and no storage for the actual value itself.

In any case, you should use whatever value works best with your queries, and optimize only when needed.

Comment: +1 for storing what's logically best for your queries. If you really have many columns that are often null or zero, maybe you need a different data model?